# Passenger 'premature end of script headers' error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ruby, phusion-passenger

I really need help debugging an error I'm getting with Passenger on Apache.

I've just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.4 and have Apache, Ruby and Passenger installed. I'm trying to run a simple rack app but keep getting this error in my Apache `error.log`

```
[Tue Sep 28 05:54:41 2010] [error] [client 86.171.2.82] Premature end of script headers:
```

The error then continues with

```
The backend application (process 25574) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
*** Exception NoMethodError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass) (process 25574):
```

I've tried older versions of passenger also but get the same error.

- Ubuntu 10.4
- Apache 2.2.14
- Ruby 1.9.2-p0
- Passenger 2.2.15

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to ensure that all of the config files used by your application are populated? ([related](http://www.coreguardian.org/2009/09/09/rack-nomethoderror-undefined-method-call-for-nilnilclass/))

Comment: Bizarre. My config.ru file was perfectly valid. However, until I separated it into a config.ru and a separate app.rb file it failed.